# How to delete the additional first empty row in the excel output of a dataframe with MultiIndex header?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a `sample_df` which has a `MultiIndex` header. When I export it to Excel by `pd.Dataframe.to_excel`, an empty row is added before the first row to show the name of the index's header (as shown in the below picture).
[image]
Is there any way to remove this additional row in the Excel output?